# How to know today is 31st dec

Tags: php, date

I wish to display something like greetings on my website.

Only if month and date is 31<sup>st</sup> December or 1<sup>st</sup> January

```
if($today =='12-31' || $today =='01-01'){    
    echo 'Greetings.';    
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the php `date()` function?

Comment: i know but how will compare help please

Comment: date shows like 2016-12-30 i want only month and date

Comment: `date('m-d') == '12-31'`

Comment: oh yes how dumb i am :)

Comment: You really try reading some PHP. I can suggest starting here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: thanks guys :) @bansi im unable to vote you but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just generate **$today** in the format you're looking up later on, using PHP's [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) `$today = date('m-d');` generates numeric {month}-{day} as demonstrated in your sample code

```
<?php

$today = date('m-d');

if($today =='12-31' || $today =='01-01'){
    echo 'Greetings.';
}

echo $today;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$yearend_date = strtotime('31 Dec');
$yearEnd = date('Y-m-d', $yearend_date);
$YearStart = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 day',$yearend_date));
$today = date('Y-m-d');

if($yearEnd==$today || $YearStart==$today){
echo "greetings";
}
```